# Which application requires to enable Azure AD based authentication, Client APP or API?

Tags: azure, asp.net-core, azure-active-directory, asp.net-core-webapi

I have two projects in a solution. One is .net core 3.0 based Web API. Next is Angular 9 SPA. I've been asked to setup Azure AD based authentication. So I enabled that in API.

But I am seriously confused where it actually requires to enable? Client App or API? or Both?

Comment: Both. You want to authenticate the end user after all, and validate whatever token is submitted to the API. If you *don't* validate the token, you have no authentication. A hacker could make calls with dummy tokens. Have you checked [the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/tutorial-single-page-app?tabs=app-reg-ga)?

Comment: [Tutorial: Enable authentication in a single-page application with Azure AD B2C](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/tutorial-single-page-app?tabs=app-reg-ga) shows how to enable Azure AD and modify the SPA. [Tutorial: Grant access to an ASP.NET web API using Azure Active Directory B2C](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/tutorial-web-api-dotnet?tabs=app-reg-ga) shows how to protect the API

Answer (score 1):

Since your client needs to call the API, it needs to authenticate to it.
And since the API requires AAD tokens, your client will need to acquire one.

So you need to implement Azure AD authentication in your client application *and* in the API.

The client's job is to authenticate the user with Azure AD and acquire an access token for the API.
It then adds that token as a header on each request:

```
Authorization: Bearer token-goes-here
```

The API then validates that token on each request.